# Variation of the rook problem with rooks of two different colours.

Tags: combinatorics

I'm sorry if this is not actually a variation on the rook problem, but it's the most similar problem I could find.

The problem is you're given a square board which has $N \times N\ (N \geq 2)$ squares, and you have two kinds of rooks: red and blue. Each row and column must have exactly one of each colour of rook.
I have found that the solution for this problem on an *empty* board is $N! \cdot !N$.

Is there a formula to figure out the amount of distinct solutions for a $N \times N$ grid with some pre-filled red and blue rooks as shown [on this board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRJfk.jpg)? The amount of rooks of a single colour can vary anywhere from $0..N$ and the amount of red and blue rooks can be different.

Comment: @PeterTaylor yes, I meant row and column, but seems like I forgot to write the other one. I've edited the question to clarify.